# Why is StringIO object slower than real file object?

Tags: python, stringio, cstringio

I'm looking through the source of `StringIO` where it says says some notes:

1. **Using a real file is often faster (but less convenient)**.
2. There's also a much faster implementation in C, called `cStringIO`, but
   it's not subclassable.

`StringIO` just like a memory file object, 
why is it slower than real file object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's file handling [is implemented entirely in C](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/file.html).  This means that it's quite fast (at least in the same order of magnitude as native C code).

The StringIO library, however, is written in Python.  The module itself is thus interpreted, with the associated performance penalties.

As you know, there is another module, cStringIO, with a [similar interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), which you can use in performance-sensitive code.
The reason this isn't subclassable is *because* it's written in C.

Comment: @sapi - is there something similar for BytesIO ?

Answer (score 4):

This is *not* actually about Python's interpreted nature: `BytesIO` is implemented in Python*, same as `StringIO`, but still beats file I/O.

In fact, `StringIO` is faster than file I/O under `StringIO`'s ideal use case (a single write to the beginning of an empty buffer). Actually, if the write is big enough it'll even beat `cStringIO`. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35185020/388033).

So why is `StringIO` considered "slow"? `StringIO`'s real problem is being backed by *immutable sequences*, whether `str` or `unicode`. This is fine if you only write once, obviously. But, as pointed out by [tdelaney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35185931/388033) to my question, it slows down a ton (like, 10-100x) when writing to random locations, since every time it gets a write in the middle it has to copy the entire backing sequence.

`BytesIO` doesn't have this problem since it's backed by a (mutable) `bytearray` instead. Likewise, whatever `cStringIO` does, it seems to handle random writes much more easily. I'd guess that it breaks the immutability rule internally, since C strings are mutable.

* Well, the version in `_pyio` is, anyway. The standard library version in `io` is written in C.

Comment: great answer, thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

It is not neccessarily obvious from the source but python file objects is built straight on the C library functions, with a likely small layer of python to present a python class, or even a C wrapper to present a python class. The native C library is going to be highly optimised to read bytes and blocks from disk. The python StringIO library is all native python code - which is slower than native C code.

Comment: ok - re-reading the question it is contradictory. A small edit is required - done :-)

Comment: sorry for my poor english, my meaning is `look through`, not `look for`.